# Discord Module never used?

Tags: python-3.7, discord.py

I'm relatively confused here, and upon trying to research for an answer, I'm not seeming to find anything that makes any sense to me. I have created a discord bot with 5 cogs, and in each one I `import discord, os, and from discord.ext import commands` In various other cogs I `import` other modules such as `random` as the case may be, but those are the three common ones.

The problem is that in every module, `import discord` is grayed out (PyCharm IDE), suggesting that is never used. Despite this, my bot runs perfectly. I don't seem to be able to use things like the `wait_for()` command, I presume it is because it is in the `discord` module? Am I not setting things up correctly to use this?

I will post the initial startup module and a small snippet of another module, rather than list module. If you need more information, let me know.

initial startup:

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

token = open("token.txt", "r").read()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension("cogs." + extension)

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension("cogs." + extension)

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension("cogs." + filename[:-3])

client.run(token)
```

another module:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import json
from pathlib import Path

class Sheet(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    @commands.command()
    @commands.dm_only()
    async def viewchar(self, ctx):

         #Snipped code here to make it shorter.
         pass

    @viewchar.error
    async def stats_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.PrivateMessageOnly):
            await ctx.send("You're an idiot, now everyone knows. Why would you want to display your character sheet "
                           "in a public room? PM me with the command.")
        else:
            raise error

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Sheet(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

That just means that your code doesn't directly reference the `discord` module anywhere.  You're getting everything through the `commands` module.

You can remove the `import discord` from your code without breaking anything, because the code that relies on it will still import and use it behind the scenes.